# "Select" con datos de diferentes tablas

Tags: php, html, mysql

necesito ayuda. Tengo que hacer crear con *PHP*, las opciones de un **select** con los datos que provenientes de diferentes tablas *MySql*, y una vez seleccionadas las inserte en otra tabla.

Tengo esta consulta *SQL*:

```
$consulta =  "SELECT idCausa,
    Deudor_idDeudor,
    Cliente_idCliente,
    TiposCausas_idTiposCausas,
    Tribunal_idTribunal,
    SubMateria,
    Rol,
    RutPerJurid,
    ClienteAsunto,
    Abogado,
    Procurador,
    Estado,
    Fecha
    FROM causa WHERE idCausa = " . $idCausa;
```

y los *JOIN* son estos:

```
$consulta = "SELECT c.idCausa, 
    DATE_FORMAT(c.Fecha, '%d.%m.%Y') 'Fecha',
    d.nombre 'Deudor', 
    cc.nombre 'Cliente',
    tc.Descripcion 'TiposCausas', 
    tb.DescTribunal 'Juzgado', 
    sm.Descripcion 'SubMateria', 
    c.Rol, c.RutPerJurid, 
    c.ClienteAsunto,
    u.nombres 'Abogado',
    pc.Procurador,
    ec.estado ,
    c.Documento
         FROM causa c
         INNER JOIN usuario u ON u.rut = c.abogado
         LEFT JOIN deudor d ON c.Deudor_idDeudor= d.idDeudor
         LEFT JOIN cliente cc ON c.Cliente_idCliente = cc.idCliente
         LEFT JOIN tiposcausas tc ON tc.idTiposCausas =  c.TiposCausas_idTiposCausas
         LEFT JOIN submateria sm ON sm.idSubTiposCausas = c.SubMateria
         LEFT JOIN tribunal tb ON tb.idTribunal = c.Tribunal_idTribunal
         LEFT JOIN procuradores pc ON pc.idProcurador = c.procurador
         LEFT JOIN estadoscausas ec ON ec.idestado = c.estado
         ORDER BY c.idCausa desc;
```

probé lo siguiente y no me funcionó:

```
<select>
    <option value="0">Selección:</option>

<?php

    $query = $mysqli -> query ( "SELECT * FROM datos" );

    while ( $valores = mysqli_fetch_array( $query )) {

        echo '<option value="' . $valores[ idcausa ]. ' ">'</option>';

    }
?>

</select>
```

¿Alguna idea de como lo pueda hacer? Necesito hacerlo urgente y se me agotan las ideas.

update hice caso de lo que me dijeron y el option sigue sin mostrar datos el codigo quedo algo asi :

```html
<?php
 
 
include("conexion.php");

header("Content-Type: text/html;charset=ISO-8859-1");
session_start();
if(isset($_SESSION['nombreusu']))
{
?>

<html lang="en">
<div class="form-group">
    <div class="form-row">
      <div class="col-md-6">
    <label for="Deudor_idDeudor">Id Deudor</label>
    <select>
       <option value="0" >Selección:</option>

    <?php

       $resultado = $mysqli -> query ( "SELECT * FROM causa" );

      while ( $valores = $resultado->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC)) {
  echo '<option value="' . $valores[ 'idcausa' ] . ' ">' . $valores[ 'idcausa' ] . '</option>';
            }
     ?>

    </select>
   </div>
 </div>
```

Comment: ¿Las consultas funcionan? ¿Las probaste en una aplicación como phpMyAdmin? ¿Hiciste debug de los resultados?

Comment: Prueba la salida de la consulta con un `while($valores = mysqli_fetch_array( $query )) {  print_r($valores); }`

Answer (score 1):

Me voy a permitir señalarte algunas cosas:

1. Estás usando el estilo orientado a objetos y el estilo por procedimientos en el mismo código.

   Aquí usas el estilo orientado a objetos:

   `$query = $mysqli -> query ( "SELECT * FROM datos" );`

   Aquí usas el estilo por procedimientos:

   `while ( $valores = mysqli_fetch_array( $query )) {`

La mezcla de estilos es [una práctica no recomendada por el Manual de PHP](http://php.net/manual/es/mysqli.quickstart.dual-interface.php), por motivos evidentes.

> *Mezclar estilos*
>
> Es posible cambiar entre los estilos en cualquier momento. No se
>   recomienda mezclar los dos estilos por razones de claridad y estilo de
>   código.

Puedes usar el estilo orientado a objetos... es más claro y es más *moderno*. Si quieres más detalles sobre esto puedes consultar la respuesta  a esta preguna: [Diferencia entre new mysqli y mysqli_connect](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/85848/29967)

2. Si quieres leer los valores usando los nombres de las columnas dentro del `while` entonces debes indicar que quieres un array asociativo en los resultados. La lectura se hace así: `$valores["idcausa"]`, indicando entre comillas `"` el nombre de la columna, lo cual falta en tu código.
3. Te falta el valor que debe mostrarse fuera del `option`. Ten en cuanta que los option tiene la siguiente sintaxis: `<option value="valor">Valor que se muestra</option>`, tu código no indica nada en `Valor que se muestra`. Supondré en la propuesta de código que quieres mostrar una columna de la tabla en la base de datos llamada `causa`.

#### CÓDIGO EDITADO

Esta es una propuesta completa, que controla todo el flujo del programa, tiene una variable `$arrError` dedicada a recoger los eventuales errores que podrían ocurrir. De ese modo el código siempre *dice* algo.

Veamos:

```
<?php
include("conexion.php");
header("Content-Type: text/html;charset=ISO-8859-1");
session_start();
if(isset($_SESSION['nombreusu']))
{
?>

<html lang="en">

<?php
        if ($mysqli){    
            $resultado = $mysqli -> query ( "SELECT * FROM causa" );
             if ($resultado->num_rows > 0){
                $strHTML='<div class="form-group">';
                $strHTML.='<div class="form-row">';
                $strHTML.='<div class="col-md-6">';
                    $strHTML.='<label for="Deudor_idDeudor">Id Deudor</label>';
                    $strHTML.='<select>';
                        $strHTML.='<option value="0" >Selección:</option>';
                while ( $valores = $resultado->fetch_assoc()) {
                        $strHTML.='<option value="' . $valores[ 'idcausa' ] . ' ">' . $valores[ 'idcausa' ] . '</option>';
                }
                    $strHTML.='</select>';
                $strHTML.='</div>';
                $strHTML.='</div>';
                $strHTML.='</div>';
                echo $strHTML;

            }else{

                $arrError=array("mensaje"=>"No se encontraron registros");      
            }

        }else{

            $arrError=array("mensaje"=>"La conexión a la base de datos no se puedo establecer. Revise conexion.php");   
        }

}else{  

    $arrError=array("mensaje"=>"No hay datos en nombreusu");

}

/*Verificamos si hubo errores*/
    if ($arrError){

        echo $arrError["mensaje"];
    }
?>
</html>
```

Comment: no me funciono este metodo :/

Comment: Tendrás que ir evaluando cada variable para ver dónde está el problema : la conexión, la consulta, etc. Cuando pueda te pondré un ejemplo.

Comment: @Tondrax he editado la respuesta con una propuesta global, implementando un código controlado. Si no funciona te dirá por qué no funciona.

Answer (score 0):

Suponiendo que tu consulta este correcta y tengas los datos al componer el ***option*** no estas imprimiendo un contenido visible, tus opciones se desplegarían vacías... Además no usas la llave del array como un string por lo que no obtendrías el dato. Debería ser:

```
    echo '<option value="' . $valores[ 'idcausa' ] . ' ">' 
. $valores[ 'idcausa' ] . '</option>';
```

Comment: Ojo, respecto a la llave mal entrecomillada, lo que  ocurre silenciosamente es : `PHP Notice:  Use of undefined constant idcausa - assumed 'idcausa'` y pasaría igual.