# multiselect a datos en una bd

Tags: php, jquery

lo que quiero hacer es que muestre en un combo multiselect los productos que estan en la bd, este es mi filtro:

```
    <label>Producto:</label>
    <select  name="product02"   id="product02" multiple="multiple">
    </select>
    </div>
    <?
        $col = $col + 2;
        $jsvars .= 'var product = $("#product02").val();
        ';
        if($fcount!==1) $params .= ',';
        $params .= 'product';
        $fproduct2 = false;
```

imagino hay que poner algun query dentro del 
Para que se muesten si alguien me puede orientar por que ya hice que fuera multiselect pero no me trae ningun dato.

así se mira

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Tienes que leer los datos de la BD e irlos metiendo dentro del `select`, como elementos `option` del mismo.

Comment: [Aquí hay un ejemplo](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/115088/29967) donde se llena un `select` tomando datos que provienen de una consulta a la base de datos. Verás que se abre un `while` que recorre el conjunto de datos y allí se colocan los elementos `option` que serán parte de ese `select`. Para que se muestre debes respetar la estructura del `select`, que es `<select>` luego cada `<option></option>` y luego cerrar el `</select>`. Y no cometer errores cuando concatenas, confundiendo comillas dobles, simples, etc.

Answer (score 1):

No me queda muy clara tu pregunta pero si entiendo bien quieres que en el select se despliegue la información de tus productos. Para esto podrías intentar lo siguiente:

```
<select  name="product02"   id="product02" multiple="multiple">
<?php 
foreach ($productos as $producto)
{
     echo "<option val=\">".$producto->id."\">".$producto->name."</option>"
}
?>
    </select>
```

Y debes retornas los datos de tus productos en un arreglo.