# No funciona la condición al ejecutar una consulta SQL en PHP

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

Estoy tratando de insertar en una tabla MySQL y estoy utilizando una condición, el código es el siguiente:

```
    function updateBadgesChamilo($DB, $DB2, $id){
    $sql = "SELECT b.name as competencia FROM skill s 
            INNER JOIN skill_rel_user sru ON s.id=sru.skill_id
            INNER JOIN user u ON u.id=sru.user_id
            INNER JOIN sm4rtuniversity.members m ON m.email=u.email
            INNER JOIN sm4rtuniversity.badges b ON b.name=s.name
            WHERE m.id = :id";

    $comunicacion;

    try{
        $statement = $DB2->prepare($sql);
        $statement->bindParam(":id", $id);
        $statement->execute();
        $resultado = $statement->fetchAll();

        if($resultado['competencia']=='Comunicacion Asertiva'){
            $comunicacion = 'si';
        }else{
            $comunicacion = 'no';
        }

        //Comunicación asertiva
        $comunicacionID = '23' ;

        $sqlComunicacion = "INSERT INTO badges_members (user_id, badge_id, active)
                            VALUES (':id',':comunicacionID',':comunicacion')
                            ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE active=':comunicacion'";

        $stmtcomunicacion = $DB->prepare($sqlComunicacion);
        $stmtcomunicacion->bindParam(":id", $id);
        $stmtcomunicacion->bindParam(":comunicacionID", $comunicacionID);
        $stmtcomunicacion->bindParam(":comunicacion", $comunicacion);
        $stmtcomunicacion->execute();


    }catch (Exception $ex) {
        $ex->getMessage();
    }

}
```

Mando llamar a esa función de la siguiente manera:

```
    updateBadgesChamilo($DB, $DB2, $user['id']);
```

En la columna active de la tabla badges_members tendría que insertarse un sí, ya que el resultado de la consulta es **"Comunicacion Asertiva"**.

[image: Comunicacion Asertiva]

Pero se inserta como un no.

[image: if]

Al parecer creo que la condición esta bien.

Pero no se que otra parte del código este funcionando de mala manera.

Comment: En tu codigo PHP te falta el WHERE

Comment: El resultado de la consulta es el mismo sin el WHERE, ya que de todos modos es el único registro que coincide.

Comment: De la manera que tienes escrita la consulta no funciona. En lugar de AND tienes que escribir WHERE

Comment: si fue un pequeño descuido, pero se igual manera sigue sin funcionar.

Comment: $row['competencia'] seguramente no trae el valor que esperas porque te falta indicar en el mysqli_fetch_array($query); el parámetro MYSQLI_ASSOC para que puedas trabajar con nombres y no index. Pruébalo, no se me ocurre otra cosa

Comment: Ya agregue el MYSQLI_ASSOC y de igual manera sigue sin funcionar.

Comment: Haz un `var_dump($row);` para revisar lo que está trayendo tu consulta realmente.

Comment: Efectivamente, esta trayendo como NULL, desconozco porque.

Comment: Lo primero que tienes que hacer cuando un código falle es: o [revisar el log de errores](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/116419/29967), o depurar tus variables: la del `$id`; la de la conexión - `$mysqli` ; la de la consulta - `$sql` y la variable `$query`. Por ejemplo, en la consulta, ¿qué es `sm4rtuniversity`, es otro schema diverso al actual en el cual hay una tabla `members`? Si el id es numérico, esta parte debe ir así: `... WHERE b.name = 'Comunicacion Asertiva'
    AND m.id = $id LIMIT 1";`

Answer (score 1):

Guillermo, prueba esta solución en la cual he optimizado tu código, dándole además seguridad contra ataques de inyección SQL.

Este es un ejemplo de código controlado en todo momento. Verás que el código usa una variable `$msgInfo`  que va recogiendo todo lo que ocurre durante el recorrido. Esa variable se imprimirá al final y te dirá siempre el resultado final de tu ejecución.

Aparte de lo ya dicho, he aplicado otras mejoras como:

- uso de estilo orientado a objetos en todo el código, puesto que tenías una mezcla de este estilo y el estilo procedural, lo cual [no es recomendable](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/85852/29967)
- cierre de recursos cuando estos no se necesiten
- uso de operador ternario para guardar valores, evitando así bloques `if ... else...`

Espero te sea de utilidad. Si no entiendes algo del código no dudes en preguntar.

```
$msgInfo="";
if ($mysqli){
    $sql = "SELECT b.name as competencia
            FROM skill s 
            INNER JOIN skill_rel_user sru ON s.id=sru.skill_id
            INNER JOIN user u ON u.id=sru.user_id
            INNER JOIN sm4rtuniversity.members m ON m.email=u.email
            INNER JOIN sm4rtuniversity.badges b ON b.name=s.name
            WHERE b.name = 'Comunicacion Asertiva'
            AND m.id = ? LIMIT 1";
    $stmt=$mysqli->prepare($sql);

    if ($stmt){ 
        $stmt->bind_param("i", $id);
        $stmt->execute();
        $stmt->bind_result($competencia);
        $stmt->fetch();
        $stmt->close();

        $comunicacionID = '23';
        $comunicacion=($competencia=='Comunicacion Asertiva') ? 'si' : 'no';
        $msgInfo.="SELECT exitoso. Comunicación tiene el valor: ".$comunicacion; 

        $sqlComunicacion = "INSERT INTO badges_members (user_id, badge_id, active)
                            VALUES (?,?,?)
                            ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE active=?";

        $stmtInsert=$mysqli->prepare($sqlComunicacion);

        if ($stmtInsert){ 
            $stmtInsert->bind_param("iiss", $id,$comunicacionID,$comunicacion,$comunicacion);
            $stmtInsert->execute();
            $stmtInsert->close();
            $msgInfo.="INSERT exitoso"; 

        }else{

            $msgInfo.="Error en el INSERT: ".$mysqli->error; 

        }

    }else{

        $msgInfo.="Error en el SELECT: ".$mysqli->error; 

    }

    $mysqli->close();

}else{

    $msgInfo.="Error en la conexión. Revise las credenciales para conectar a la base de datos"; 

}

echo $msgInfo;
```

Comment: Gracias por el còdigo, ya lo cambie a PDO para que este sea un poco màs seguro pero sigue sin funcionar. Mi duda es que la siguiente: Como trabajo con dos bases de datos distintas tal vez PHP no este reconociendo esto o no se .

Comment: @GuillermoRicardoSpindolaBri Si lo cambiaste a PDO mucho mejor. En caso de necesitar trabajar con dos BD distintas tan sólo tendrías que crear dos objetos de conexión y usar el que necesites según la DB/Tabla que vayas a consultar.  Por ejemplo: `$pdo1=new PDO (*credenciales BD 1*);  $pdo2=new PDO (*credenciales BD 2*);` y luego usas `$pdo1` o `$pdo2` según el caso.