# ayuda con php Parse error: syntax error, unexpected end of file in C:\xampp\htdocs\registro\ajax\conec.php on line 16

Tags: php, ajax

```
<?php
function connectDB(){
    $server = "localhost ";
    $user = "$usuario";
    $pass = "$passwoord";
    $bd = "nombre base de datos";
    global $link;
    if (!($link=mssqli_connect("local host","usuario","password"))){
        exit();
    }
    if (!mssqli_select_db("base de datos",$link)){
        exit();
    }
    return $link;
}
function ConnectBD(){;
?>
```

hola tengo un problema con el php me marca error ya modifique el short tag pero sigue botando el error ayuda

Comment: pon el código, sino como esperas que sepamos por qué te manda el error? Aunque muy probablemente solo sea error de sintaxis, , así que revisa bien el código en esa linea

Comment: Si tu intencion es llamar a la funcion, debes hacerlo asi: `connectDB();`

Answer (score 1):

Hay unas cuantas malas prácticas en tu código y errores de sintaxis.

Vamos a tratar de corregirlos. Iré comentando en el código:

```
<?php
function connectDB(){
    $server = "localhost"; //sobraba un espacio
    $user = "usuario";     //tenía una $ dentro
    $pass = "passwoord";   //tenía una $ dentro y... ¿lleva dos oo?
    $bd = "nombre base de datos";  //poner datos reales en todo esto

    /*
       -no usaremos global, es una mala práctica, 
        ver al respecto: https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/29177/29967
       -la función se llama mysqli_connect, no mssqli_connect
       -usa las variables, que para algo las tienes
       -puedes seleccionar la bd de una vez en la conexión
    */


    if (!($link = mysqli_connect($server,$user,$pass,$bd))){
        echo "error de conexión: " . mysqli_connect_error() . PHP_EOL;
        exit();
    }

    return $link;
}

/*
    Dado que la función devuelve el objeto $link
    debes usar una asignación de variable cuando la llamas
*/
$link=ConnectBD();
//Usar $link para lo que quieras...
?>
```

---

**SUGERENCIA:**

Si estás empezando con mysqli, recomendaría que uses el estilo orientado a objetos. Es más claro y más moderno que el estilo procedural. Para más detalles puedes consultar esta pregunta:

**- [Diferencia entre new mysqli y mysqli_connect](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/85848/29967)**

Comment: muchas gracias, revisaré el contenido, modificaré las lineas

Answer (score 0):

hay un error de sintaxis aqui `function ConnectBD(){;` si quieres llamar la funcion basta con poner `ConnectBD();`

Comment: tambien fijate aquí `if (!($link=mssqli_connect("local host","usuario","password"))){` supongo que `localhost` debería ir junto.