# No se ven mis registros de mysql en el select

Tags: php, javascript, mysql

buen dia
tengo una consulta
lo que necesito hacer es mostrar mis registros de una tabla en un opcion select y este a su vez los pueda mandar en un form pero no me los muestra

```
<div align="center"> 
    <p>Seleccione un pais del siguiente menú:</p>
    <p>Paises:
      <select>
        <option value="0">Seleccione:</option>
        <?php
// Realizamos la consulta para extraer los datos
          $query = $mysqli -> query ("SELECT * FROM generales");
          while ($valores = mysqli_fetch_array($query)) {
// En esta sección estamos llenando el select con datos extraidos de una base de datos.
            echo '<option value="'.$valores['id'].'" name=departamento >'.$valores['departamento'].'</option>';
          }
        ?>
      </select>
      <button>Enviar</button>
    </p>
  </div>
```

entonces quiero que se vean los registros que tengo almacenados en la base de datos y de paso poderlos guardar con el form

agrego captura de como se ve en la pantalla
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Segun la documentacion, https://www.php.net/manual/es/mysqli-result.fetch-array.php, no es asi como es usa mysqli_fetch_array

Comment: pero si lo tengp si

Comment: mysqli_fetch_array

Comment: Vuelvo a repetir, leiste la documentacion? la funcion no se usa como la estas usando vos...

Comment: Estas usando dos estilos diferentes **Estilo orientado a objetos** y luego **por procedimientos**, intenta esto `$valores = $query->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC);`

Comment: ya lo agrege pero no me aparece nada           while ($valores = $query->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC)($query)) {

Comment: Como consejo no deberias hacer consultas en la vista.

Comment: `while ($valores = $query->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC)($query)) {` no está bien formado, fíjate en mi ejemplo `$valores = $query->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC) {`, cópialo tal cual sin **($query)** o también puedes usar la función `fetch_assoc()`, es decir, `while ($valores = $query->fetch_assoc()) {`

Answer (score 3):

Realmente tu código no es erróneo. Pero implementas malas prácticas al mezclar el estilo orientado a objetos: `$query = $mysqli -> query ("SELECT * FROM generales");` y el estilo procedural: `while ($valores = mysqli_fetch_array($query)) {`. Esto es desaconsejado<sup>1</sup>, porque produce un código confuso y revela poco rigor en el estilo de programación. Dado que el estilo orientado a objetos es más sencillo y más claro, vamos a optar por él en la respuesta.

El motivo por el que tu código no estaría funcionando es porque faltan controles. En una consulta deberías verificar siempre lo siguiente:

- Que hay conexión
- Que no hay error en la consulta (en una consulta del tipo `SELECT` podría haber errores de sintaxis, en consultas de otro tipo puede haber errores de violación de restricciones como PK duplicada u otras)
- Que hay registros (en una consulta del tipo SELECT como la de este código)

El problema es que se suele programar pensando que todo saldrá bien (a lo que yo llamo *programación optimista* y que es un error de concepto que produce programas débiles). Hay que programar pensando que cualquier cosa puede salir mal (*programación pesimista*) y la tarea del programador es responder cuando algo salga mal. Ese estilo de programación produce un código robusto a prueba de todo lo que salga mal.

Propongo esto:

```
<div align="center"> 
    <p>Seleccione un pais del siguiente menú:</p>
    <p>Paises:
      <select>
        <option value="0">Seleccione:</option>
        <?php
            #¿Hay conexión?
            if ($mysqli) {
                $query = $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM generales");
                #¿No hay error de consulta y hay filas?
                if ($query &&  $query->num_rows >0) {
                    #Usaremos un método más específico: fetch_assoc
                    $mOptions="";
                    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
                        $mOptions.="<option value=\"$row[id]\" name=\"departamento\">$row[departamento]</option>";
                    }       
                } else {
                    /*
                        Esto lo puedes cambiar, 
                        como opción simple he decidido poner el motivo del error en el option
                        realmente deberías implementar tu propia política de errores
                        mostrando por ejemplo los mensajes de error en un contenedor
                    */
                    $mOptions="<option value=\"-1\" name=\"departamento\">Error de consulta o 0 filas</option>";
                }   
                
            } else {
                $mOptions="<option value=\"-1\" name=\"departamento\">No hay conexión</option>";
            }
            echo $mOptions;
        ?>
      </select>
      <button>Enviar</button>
    </p>
  </div>
```

Ahora tendrás en el `option` los valores obtenidos o un mensaje con lo que haya ocurrido. Como ya dije en comentarios del código, podrías implementar tu propia política de errores, en la cual decidirías no llenar el `select` en caso de error y mostrar en algún contenedor (un `div` u otro)  un mensaje de error o lo que quieras.

---

#### Notas

1. En [mi respuesta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/85852/29967)  a la pregunta *[Diferencia entre new mysqli y mysqli_connect](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/85848/29967)* he tratado de explicar ese problema basándome en la documentación. Realmente la mezcla de estilos no produce código erróneo, simplemente es una mala práctica por lo que se explica en la respuesta.

Comment: Sigue las recomendaciones de A. Cedano, en lo personal me ayudaron mucho con las buenas practicas, aunque todavía me falta mejorar.

Answer (score 0):

Veo que andas un poco confuso. Como te he escrito en el comentario, no es buena práctica mezclar los estilos a la hora de trabajar con nuestra Base de Datos.

Aun así, faltan detalles en tu código para poder ver donde esta tu fallo preciso, siempre es bueno ejecutar nuestra consulta en el **phpMyAdmin** y ver su trae resultados y así verificar que está formado correctamente. 
`SELECT * FROM generales`

También te aconsejo que compruebas tu conexión lanzando algún mensaje. 
`if ($mysqli->connect_errno) { #mensaje de error }`


Supongamos que tu conexión está formado al *estilo objeto* :

```
$mysqli = new mysqli("localhost", "mi_usuario", "mi_contraseña", "nombre_bd");
```

**Ejemplo práctico**

```
<?php
$mysqli = new mysqli("localhost", "mi_usuario", "mi_contraseña", "nombre_bd");

/* verificar la conexión */
if ($mysqli->connect_errno) {
    printf("Conexión fallida: %s\n", $mysqli->connect_error);
    exit();
}

$consulta = "SELECT * FROM generales";

if ($resultado = $mysqli->query($consulta)) {

    /* obtener un array asociativo */
    while ($valores = $resultado->fetch_assoc()) {
        echo "<option value={$valores['id']} name='departamento'> {$valores['departamento']} </option>";
    }

    /* liberar el conjunto de resultados */
    $resultado->free();
}
```

Aun asi te aconsejo usar sentencias preparadas.

**[Ejemplo sentencia preparada](https://www.php.net/manual/es/mysqli-stmt.prepare.php)**

```
/* La conexión */
$mysqli = new mysqli("localhost", "mi_usuario", "mi_contraseña", "nombre_bd");

/* Consulta */
$consulta = "SELECT id,departamento FROM generales";

/* crear una sentencia preparada */
$sentencia = $mysqli->prepare($consulta);

/* ejecutar la consulta */
if (!$sentencia->execute()) {
    echo "Falló la ejecución: (" . $sentencia->errno . ") " . $sentencia->error;
}

/* almacenar el resultado */
$sentencia->store_result();

/* Comprobar que existen registros */
if ($sentencia->num_rows > 0) {
     /* vincular las variables de resultados */
     $sentencia->bind_result($id,$departamento);

     /* obtener el valor */
     while ($sentencia->fetch() ) {
         echo "<option value=$id name='departamento'> $departamento </option>";
     }
 } else { # Mensaje, no existen resultados en BD }

 /* cerrar la sentencia */
 $sentencia->close();
```

Te dejo un enlace de como evitar la [inyeccion SQL en PHP](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/18232/c%C3%B3mo-evitar-la-inyecci%C3%B3n-sql-en-php).